# Created a startup company which is growing, but I'm far too inexperienced to do anything. How do I move on?

Tags: management, startup, leadership

I haven't graduated university yet, and I created a startup company which is growing. There is no co-founder. It's just me. The issue is, I need to get some money in order to keep the servers running, in order to get backup servers, in order to improve the software and the user interface etc.. I need to hire workers. I decided, maybe if I pitch the idea to investors, they would give me money to do what is needed to be done if I give them a certain percentage of the company.

The issue is, I have absolutely no experience in any of this. I'm a computer science student who knows how to program, and that's about it. I don't even know how investment works and how to properly pitch an idea. I'm not even great in presentations and have a long way to go in becoming a professional worker in the workplace. I can enroll in courses and read books and learn but I don't have that much time as the company is growing.

I decided, maybe I can pay someone to pitch the idea for me and to give the presentations and to help me out a bit? I went to my uncle who's a manager and a fairly large company and who has some experience in this stuff, but he said he's not doing the job for me. I went to a friend, who said he'll only help if I give him a percentage of the company. So then I decided to put up a job posting, but I don't even know how to make a proper job posting / interview candidates / find the right candidate. I don't even know what the job title would be called.

I'm currently reading books on management, leadership, efficiency, entrepreneurship etc.. (books like "Good to Great" and "7 habits of very effective people") but I don't think it's helping in my current situation (although the books are great and I did learn a lot from them).

With that said, any idea what I do from here? I don't want to sell the entire company because I think that as the founder and one who set the initial vision of the company and got the company to grow, I should continue pitching ideas / helping set the vision and direct the company. However, I can't think of any other solution to my situation other than just letting someone else more experienced take over.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more appropriate on http://startups.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You need to break off relations with your "Uncle" and your sponge "friend".

Comment: @Jack - really? Your nephew comes to you and says "I don't know what I'm doing here", and telling him "I can't do it for you" is out of line? Your friend tells you "I'm doing this startup and I need your help" and telling him "Sure, I'll do it with you if I get equity" is wrong? To me, it sounds like the friend *could* be the solution, and giving employee #2 equity in a barely-started company is fairly common.

Comment: If the op can get along with the friend and believes that he can do the job, he sounds like a better option than recruitingn a stranger

Answer (score 3):

In the United States the Small Business Administration of the US government runs Small Business Development Centers in conjunction with many colleges and universities. These SBDCs help small businesses got over their obstacles. Best of all their advice is free.